# fatal error: ini.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, c++

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** on **Dell Vostro 15 - 3546**.

```
uname -api
Linux vaishnavi-laptop 4.15.0-118-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 8 12:30:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When try installing [comfortable-swipe](https://github.com/Hikari9/comfortable-swipe), the output of `bash install` is:

```
Installing binaries ...
./comfortable-swipe-main.cpp:41:10: fatal error: ini.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ini.h> // ini_parse
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the package needed with apt-file:

```
    apt-file search include/ini.h  
libinih-dev: /usr/include/ini.h
```

So install the libinih-dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install libinih-dev
```

Comment: thanks for letting us know about apt-file, didn't know about that before. really useful.